# React dropdown issue

Tags: reactjs, firebase, filter, dropdown

I have a dropdown component and data from Firebase which I need to filter out. The first time, selection works, but the second time I get an empty state and can't select all or make a new selection.
Thanks a lot in advance.

*Main component with DB reference and filter function:*

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import firebase from "../firebase";
import Categories from "./Categories";

const TourMenu = () => {
const [tours, setTours] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const dbRef = firebase.database().ref();

  dbRef.on("value", (snapshot) => {
    const data = snapshot.val();
    const newToursArray = [];

  for (let inventoryName in data) {
    const toursObject = {
      id: inventoryName,
      name: data[inventoryName].name,
      category: data[inventoryName].category,
      seats: data[inventoryName].seats,
      date: data[inventoryName].date,
    };
    newToursArray.push(toursObject);
   }
   setTours(newToursArray);
  });
}, []);

 const filterItemsCat = (category) => {
    if (category === "all") {
      setTours(tours);
      return;
    }
    const newItems = tours.filter((item) => item.category === category);
    setTours(newItems);

  };

  return (
  <div>
  <h1>Hello from tour menu</h1>

  <Categories filterItemsCat={filterItemsCat} />

  {tours
    .sort((a, b) => a.date > b.date)
    .map((x) => {
      return (
        <div
          key={x.id}
          style={{
            border: "solid 1px",
            bordercolor: "grey",
            width: "230px",
            margin: "10px auto",
          }}
        >
          <p>{x.name}</p>
          <p>{x.category}</p>
          <p>date: {x.date}</p>
          <p>seats: {x.seats}</p>
        </div>
      );
    })}

  <h2>{tours.length === 0 && "hold on ..."}</h2>
</div>
  );
};

export default TourMenu;
```

*here is dropdown component (categories hardcoded for now):*

```
import React from "react";

function Categories({ categories, filterItemsCat }) {
 
  return (
    <div className="categories-container wrapper">
      <div className="btn-container">
        <select onChange={(e) => filterItemsCat(e.target.value)}>
          <option value="">--Please choose category--</option>
          <option value="all">--CHOOSE ALL--</option>
          <option value="land">land</option>
          <option value="water">water</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Categories;
```

Comment: Can you create a code sandbox(https://codesandbox.io/) for the same?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for your time and help. Actually, in order to be able to set the state again after choosing the category, I should've also had state for categories.

```
    setCategories(newToursArray);
```

And have to had two filter functions like this:

```
  const filterItemsCat = (category, filterParam) => {
    if (category && category !== "all") {
      setTours(categories.filter((x) => x.category === category));
    } else {
      setTours(categories);
    }
  };
  const filterItemsDate = (filterParam) => {
    setTours(categories.filter((item) => item.date === filterParam));
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the thing about filtering data - you need to keep all of your data intact in state so you can continue to filter it. Your useEffect() runs only once to fetch the data because its dependency array is empty [(don't do this)](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/), and you replace the data you have in state once you filter it (by calling setTours(newItems). Now all you've got in state is one category of data - how are you going to filter for other categories now when you've "erased" the other categories by replacing them in your component's state? Try storing the currently selected category in state and just deriving the displayed tours like this instead:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import firebase from "../firebase";
import Categories from "./Categories";

const TourMenu = () => {
const [tours, setTours] = useState([]);
const [category, setCategory] = useState("all");

useEffect(() => /* ... */, []);

// instead of this
// const filterItemsCat = (category) => {
//    if (category === "all") {
//      setTours(tours);
//      return;
//    }
//    const newItems = tours.filter((item) => item.category === category);
//    setTours(newItems);
//  };

// try this
const filteredTours = tours.filter((item) => item.category === category);

return (
  <div>
  <h1>Hello from tour menu</h1>

  // we'll have to change the event handler
  <Categories onChange={(newCategory) => setCategory(newCategory)} />

  {filteredTours
    .sort((a, b) => a.date > b.date)
    .map((x) => {
      return (
        <div
          key={x.id}
          style={{
            border: "solid 1px",
            bordercolor: "grey",
            width: "230px",
            margin: "10px auto",
          }}
        >
          <p>{x.name}</p>
          <p>{x.category}</p>
          <p>date: {x.date}</p>
          <p>seats: {x.seats}</p>
        </div>
      );
    })}

  <h2>{tours.length === 0 && "hold on ..."}</h2>
</div>
  );
}
```

React components are *just function*, so everytime there's a new render with a new state reality (i.e. the category has changed) the filteredTours variable will have the stuff you need!